# Migrating from Eclipse to Android Studio how to use additional scripts to produce res and gen

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

In Eclipse the team uses a python script to produce some strings in the res folder this in turn updates gen.

I want to know how to include this in intellij/ Android Studio. Is there some place I can hook into this process?

We are in early stages of migration so do not use gradle to build yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can create custom tasks in your build.gradle configuration and then set them as dependencies for the appropriate default tasks. For instance, I needed to run a python script before my build so I did it like this:

```
task myCustomTask(type:Exec, description: 'Run the pre-build python script') {
    workingDir 'scripts'
    commandLine 'python', 'my_script.py'
}
// This ensures my script will be called before building
preBuild.dependsOn myCustomTask
```

Comment: Ah sorry forgot to elaborate, since this is early stages of migration we do not build via gradle yet :(  That will come in eventually.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how to help you then.